# Automatically reposition Jquery SimpleModal to center of page when modal div is resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, simplemodal

I'm using the SimpleModal Jquery plugin and it works great!

However, there are times that the width and height of the modal div need to be changed, so I need the modal to automatically re-position itself in the center of the page. I found out that SimpleModal uses its setPosition() function to do this. It is automatically called when the modal is launched.

So I tried to call the said function when the modal div's dimensions change, but it doesn't work:

```
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    //code here to resize the modal
    $.modal.impl.setPosition(); //doesn't work. note that at this point, the modal is still active (displayed)
});
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current version (1.3.5), you can re-position the dialog in the callback. For example:

```
$('#foo').modal({
    onShow: function (dialog) {
        var modal = this; // you now have access to the SimpleModal object

        // do stuff here

        // re-position
        modal.setPosition();
    }
});
```

I'm working on version 1.3.6 which will provide some convenience methods for these "utility" functions.

Answer (score 3):

When you make an element (let's call it `theElement`) into a modal, it will be wrapped by a `div#simplemodal-container`. `div#simplemodal-container` will get the same dimentions as `theElement` (in fact, it will be 2px higher/wider than `theElement`)

You don't say what element you are actually resizing, but I guess it's `theElement`. If that's the case, `#simplemodal-container`'s dimentions aren't updated, and positioning it again will have no effect. You have to resize the container explicitly.

Therefore, after resizing and before positioning again, do this:

```
$("#simplemodal-container").css({height: newHeight, width: newWidth});
```

Here i assume `newHeight` and `newWidth` is `theElement`'s new dimentions (+2 if you want to follow simplemodal's policy)

Comment: I did this and followed it by calling $.modal.setPosition()...  and that worked for me.

Comment: @Blaise Would like to confirm that combining 2 lines together worked for me too.  $("#simplemodal-container").css({height: newHeight, width: newWidth}); and right $.modal.setPosition();

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var modal = $.modal("<div>...</div>");


$('#mybutton').click(function() {
    //code here to resize the modal
    modal.setPosition();
});
```